# Plotting a histogram from a dat file using pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I want to create a histogram from a dat file with two columns, error and frequency. It also has a large amount of bins, 501.

I have followed instructions provided elsewhere on this site but the data between major x-axis grids were omitted

The code I used is shown below

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{col sep=semicolon}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    enlarge x limits=false,
    enlarge y limits=upper,
    axis lines*=left,
    xmajorgrids,
    grid style={white,ultra thin},
    axis on top,
    tick align=outside
  ]
    \addplot [
        hist={bins=501, data min=-2.5, data max=2.5},
        fill=black!75, draw=none
    ] table [y index=0] {630LFanStats.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How should the .csv file be compiled?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx Neil! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of our site.

Comment: I don't think formatting of csv file is the problem (in your case separator is set to semicolon). Are you sure to need bins of 501 samples?

Comment: The problem I am having is only data on the major x-axis grid marks, such as 0,1,2,etc is being plotted although I have several data points in between these marks

Comment: Without some data to work from, we are not really likely to be able to answer here.